# Maven - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (1-pre-dist) on project

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm using wso2 emm 2.2.0 Beta, Please refer the below error console. when I run the maven install I got maven assembly plugin issue.

So please let me know why it occurs? and give some suggestion to fix this problem.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WSO2 Mobile Device Manager (MDM) - Distribution 2.2.0-BETA2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- incremental-build-plugin:1.3:incremental-build (default) @ wso2emm ---
[INFO] Verifying module descriptor ...
[INFO] Verifying parent modules...
[INFO] Verifying resources...
[INFO] Resources directory does not exist : /home/next/Praveen/Project/secureON/Project/Project_Setup/product-emm-2.2.0-BETA2/modules/distribution/src/main/resources
[INFO] Verifying sources...
[INFO] No sources to check ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (default) @ wso2emm ---
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 27 Oct 2016 at timestamp: 1477554746130
[WARNING] Cannot get the branch information from the git repository: 
Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/next/Praveen/Project/secureON/Project/Project_Setup/product-emm-2.2.0-BETA2/modules/distribution && git rev-parse --verify HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /home/next/Praveen/Project/secureON/Project/Project_Setup/product-emm-2.2.0-BETA2/modules/distribution
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN_BRANCH
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ wso2emm ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (1-pre-dist) @ wso2emm ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: /home/next/Praveen/Project/secureON/Project/Project_Setup/product-emm-2.2.0-BETA2/modules/distribution/src/assembly/dist.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.203s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 27 13:22:26 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/188M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (1-pre-dist) on project wso2emm: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive dist: You must set at least one file.
```

Comment: Are you going to build the 2.2.0 beta tag from root pom?

Comment: Yes, But i don't know. how to do that? I want to build the product zip bundle.

Comment: You can clone the product-emm repo and checkout v2.2.0-BETA tag and execute mvn clean install from root folder.

Comment: Ya.. We also tried that but we got error like `Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-config-processor-plugin:config-processor-maven-plugin:2.6:process (add-custom-security-headers) on project wso2emm: Error during config processing: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

Comment: I can build without any issue. what is the java version and maven version you used?

Comment: I'm using java 1.7.0_79 and maven 3.0.5

Comment: `[INFO] WSO2 Mobile Device Manager (MDM) - Distribution ... FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -----------
[INFO] Total time: 18:21.149s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 27 14:37:24 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/391M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-config-processor-plugin:config-processor-maven-plugin:2.6:process (add-custom-security-headers) on project wso2emm: Error during config processing: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out`

Comment: It seems like you are not in v2.2.0-BETA tag. There is no maven goal called `config-process‌​or-maven-plugin` in emm project. Could you confirm by issuing `git branch` command in terminal?

Comment: I just tell what I am tried.Actually I pull the latest source code from product emm git repository and open the porject in intelliJ and build the parent root using maven install. and I'm not clear what you said? :(

Comment: First i tried in beta then I clone the latest source code from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build WSO2 EMM 2.2.0 Beta follows the below steps.

1. Clone the product-emm repo
   `git clone https://github.com/wso2/product-emm.git`
2. Checkout the v2.2.0-BETA tag.
   `git checkout v2.2.0-BETA`
3. Build from root pom. Go to project root folder and issue
   `mvn clean install`

If you want just product zip you can build the distribution module for that go to project root -> modules ->distribution folder and issue `mvn clean install` from there. you can find the build zip file in `distribution/target` folder.

It seems like you are in master branch. The failing maven goal for you added after the emm beta tag creation. The reason for failing is, in build time it tries to connect to some resources in internet and your computer failed to connect to that resources on internet. If you really want to build the master branch (2.2.0-SNAPSHOT), just check your internet connection or firewall blockings.